# How does Tir compare to other Lua web frameworks?

Tags: multithreading, web-applications, lua, web-frameworks

How does Zed Shaw's **Lua** web framwork called [**Tir**](http://tir.mongrel2.org/home), compare to other Lua web frameworks such as [Kepler](http://www.keplerproject.org/), [LuCI](http://luci.subsignal.org/), etc?

Comparison to such things like:

- maturity of code base
- features/functionality
- performance
- ease of use

**UPDATE**:

Since Tir is based on the use of Lua's [**coroutine**](http://www.lua.org/pil/9.1.html), doesn't this imply that Tir will never be able to scale well? Reason being, Lua's coroutine's cannot take advantage of multi-core/processor systems given that coroutines are implemented in Lua as a cooperative/collaborative threads (as opposed to pre-emptive)?

Comment: *LuaRocks* is not a web framework.

Answer (score 1):

Tir is much newer than Kepler or LuCI, so the code isn't nearly as mature. I would rank Tir as experimental, right now. The same factor also means that it has significantly fewer features.

It *does* have a very pleasant continuation passing style of development available though, through its coroutine based flow stuff.

I would rate it, personally, as fun for experimentation, but probably not ready for heavy lifting until Zed stabilizes it more :-)

Comment: you made mention of Tir being designed around the use of coroutines. Isn't that a negative given that coroutines cannot utilize multi-cores/processesor?

Comment: In some contexts it is a negative, yes, but in that context very few standard web things do as they tend to be thread or process bound in general.

Relying on co-routines means *you* need to come back to the same lua_State instance, but other users don't need to.

Answer (score 1):

[This video](http://pycon.blip.tv/file/4883016/) from PyCon 2011 says basically you scale on multicore or multiprocessor by running more workers, under high load condition the memory advantage gives better performance.
In the video it's said that at Meebo's they have used this approach for last months with huge load.

The video is python specific, so it's just for the scaling of coroutine approach part of the question. Video length is about thirty minutes.